# Case Inbound Email Capture Format

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Evening All,

Is there a way in NetSuite to force all inbound emails, received via the Support/Case Inbound Email Capture feature, to be forced to plain email as opposed to an HTML email?

My requirement is a script which will parse the body of the email and grab information selectively and insert into Case fields.

Appreciate your response(s).

Comment: Not to be confused with a script to do this, which I already have... Just making sure there is no "feature" or similar that can be turned on to force it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not possible to do natively.